# ANTLR Returning more than one tree in a rewrite

Tags: c#, multithreading, tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking to devise a way to input an AST into a tree walker, and rewrite it such that I can get more than one output.

The reason I want to do this is because my language has 'ambiguous' semantics. At the basic level I have about 12 data types but depending upon where you see them in the tree, and under what operators then there is more than one possible output.

I would then pass each of the those outputs to even more tree rewriters, that again can produce more than one output. What I have essentially is a combinatorial explosion, and I'm looking for a way to deal with it.

Rather than having a single output, like a traditional compiler, I want to be able to keep all the possible outputs around so I can say to the user 'I think it's this....but it could also be this'.

I was thinking that I could clone the tree node stream, and pass it to the tree rewriter in a separate thread. This way we can get tree writing done in parallel.

Any thoughts or ideas on the feasibility of these concepts?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to generate all the tree variants. Can't you store the uncertainty information for a single node in that node instead of forking the object?

Comment: At the moment I store a table of probabilities in each Node/Symbol relating to how likely it is that this Node/Symbol is a certain type.
so [0.25,0.5,0.1...] means that it's 25% likely to be a number, 50% likely to be a variable, 10% likely to be a function, etc.

Comment: Sounds like you can collect all "uncertain" nodes in a list and generate all combinations from that list. After you've decided on one you can visit the AST again and apply the decision. (I might have misunderstood your problem though.)

Comment: That's sort of the right idea. The problem is basically like natural-language processing. There are many possible routes that you can use to interpret a sentence. The next word might change the whole 'meaning' of the sentence though, so you might have to explore another possible route.